# Sequential Rule Mining using Apriori Algorithm and others

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sequential, apriori

I am performing Sequential Rule Mining using Apriori Algorithm and FPA, I have the dataset in excel as shown below, I load my data into pandas dataframe what I am using is the following read_excel command as shown below.

```
    Station1    Station2    Station3    Repetition
0   Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)  Terminal 1  Universal Studios Singapore 52
1   Gardens by the Bay  Flower Dome Cloud Forest    52
2   Marina Bay Sands    Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)  Gardens by the Bay  52
3   Singapore   Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)  Gardens by the Bay  51
4   Universal Studios Singapore Singapore Changi Airport (SIN)  Marina Bay Sands    51
```

How should I perform Pattern Mining.

I used MLxtend for apriori and association rules, but on the sparse df of the Stations, excluding the Repetitions.

I am interested in Apriori, GSM, SPAM and SPADE, how can I achieve that?

TIA!!!